# How to set the current rootview in the popover?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have UISplitView Controller, on a button click im removing the rootView and the detailView and adding a new rootView and DetailView, but when i turn the iPad in the potrait mode and when i click the popover button, it displays the old rootView than displaying the new rootViewController.....any help???

```
UINavigationController *rootNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:attractObj]; 
UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:attDetailObj]; 
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailNav,nil];
splitViewController.delegate=rootViewController; 
[window addSubview:splitViewController.view]; 
//[attDetailObj.view sizeToFit]
```

Comment: Why do you have two navigation controllers?

Answer (score 0):

What i think from your above question. When you first time set the UIPopoverController's ViewController. Then it's not be change after you change the root view controller in landscape mode.

So you have to represent UIPopover view controller with new view controller. Because without that UIPopover not getting refreshed and always display old view controller.

Thanks.